# Injected Dependencies become undefined in angular service

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular service:

```
.service("MyService", ["$q", "myDep1", "myDep2", function ($q, myDep1, myDep2) {
    function aFunction() {
        //Breakpoint 2
    }

    return { //Breakpoint 1
        aFunction: aFunction
    }
}]);
```

At `Breakpoint 1` (where the service is defined), `myDep1` and `myDep2` are defined. When my controller calls `aFunction` and I hit `Breakpoint 2`, these dependencies are undefined (although $q is still defined).

What gives?? I tried changing it to a `factory` but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
.service("MyService", ["$q", "myDep1", "myDep2", function ($q, myDep1, myDep2) {
    this.aFunction = function() {
     // myDep1, myDep2 can be accessed here
    }

}]);
```

Now, In your controller you can call `MyService.aFunction()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but with a .provider

Try my solution here [Injected Dependency is undefined in Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36201905/injected-dependency-is-undefined-in-unit-test/36209633#36209633)

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different use case, but my solution worked for me. I'd like to see one that seems less of a hack to me though, if anyone has one.

I injected the dependency into the function like so:

```
.service("MyService", ["$q", "myDep1", function ($q, myDep1) {

  // add myDep1 as a param in aFunction
  function aFunction(_myDep1_) {
    // myDep1 is in scope via _myDep1_
  }

  // calling aFunction here and passing in myDep1 will pass that dependency into the function
  aFunction(myDep1);

  return { //Breakpoint 1
    aFunction: aFunction
  }
}]);
```

Note: If you call myService.aFunction() from another place in the app, you will have to pass in myDep1 as a param, which is definitely ugly. If you find you start doing that a lot, you probably have an antipattern at work somwhere. I don't feel this is the best way to do this, but in a pinch it works.